# Need to prove that there is a continuous sequence which contains 100 cup of coffee , i.e. a man drinks one cup of coffee at the day.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A man can drink at least one cup of coffee at the day. After one year he drinks 500 cup of coffee. Need to prove that there is a continuous sequence which contains 100 cup of coffee, i.e. a man drinks one cup of coffee at the day.
I suppose that the task somehow is connected with the finding of the monotone paths.

Comment: If he can drink one cup of coffee per day, how is that after a year he drinks more than $366$ cups of coffee? There must be something wrong.

Comment: Presumably this is a sequence of $365$ positive integers $X_i$, with $\displaystyle S_j=\sum_{i=1}^j X_i$ where $S_0=0$ and $S_{365}=500$ and you want to show that there must exist $j,k$ with $S_j-S_k=100$

Comment: At least one cup of coffee.

Comment: Henry- Yes thats it, how can it be done ?

Comment: Similar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820425/pigeonhole-principle-and-finite-sequences

Comment: The original version on mse seem to be http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15903/chess-master-problem

Comment: At least one cup of coffee without an upper limit doesn't prevent him from drinking 500 cups in one day (if he survives, that is !)

Comment: @trueblueanil: there is an upper limit of $500$ a year and a lower limit of $1$ a day, leading to an upper limit of $500-364=134$ a day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of cups of coffee drunk on the $i$th day is $X_i$ and $\displaystyle S_j=\sum_{i=1}^j X_i$ then $S_0=0$ and $S_{365}=500$.

Now consider the set $\{S_0,S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_{365}\}\cup\{S_0+100,S_1+100,S_2+100,\ldots,S_{365}+100\}$

The union has at most $601$ distinct elements even though each of the two subsets has $366$ distinct elements and $601<2×366$ so there must be a duplicate pair by the pigeonhole principle

As the elements in the first subset are all distinct, as are those in the second half, a duplicate pair must have one term of the form $S_j$ and the other of the form  $S_k+100$, in which case $S_j-S_k=100$ and so $100$ cups were drunk from the $k+1$th day through to the $j$th day

Comment: It would be better to say that the union has at least $730$ elements since we need to know that there are at least $601$ elements (the smallest number is at least $1$ since he drinks at least one cup of coffee a day) in the union in order to draw the desired conclusion.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Or perhaps say that the union has at most $601$ distinct elements even though each of the two subsets has $366$ distinct elements and $601 \lt 2 \times 366$

Comment: I like the formulation in your comment more than the one in your original answer since "potentially up to $732$ elements" could be less than $600$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - thank you - I have edited it